# Docker compose spring boot couldn't connect to mysql db

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have spring boot application which connects to mysql database. If I run it locally in a classic way it works fine. But when I try do dockerise it - database starts successfully but the application doesn't see the DB.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
ADD start-local.sh /start-local.sh
RUN chmod +x start-local.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "./start-local.sh" ]
```

My start-local.sh (I added it in order my application waited for database start):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Waiting for the database server to start"
echo "********************************************************"
apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat
while ! nc -z mysql 3306; do sleep 3; done
echo "******** Database Server has started"
echo "Starting account service"
java -jar /mnt/service-2.4.0.jar
```

And finally my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.23
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    entrypoint:
      sh -c "echo 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS books;  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS notifications' > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql;/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --sql_mode="""
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  account_app:
    image: service_img
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local"
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    volumes:
      - "/build/libs/:/mnt"
```

What I execute:

- first of all, I build my service_img
- then I execute docker-compose up.
  In logs, I see database starting logs, after my application starting logs and then error:

> | 2019-09-23 09:51:14.006 DEBUG [account-service,,,] 286 --- [
>   main] c.m.l.c.c.d.p.DatasourceConfiguration    : Creating datasource
>   account_app_1  | 2019-09-23 09:51:14.014  INFO [account-service,,,]
>   286 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       :
>   HikariPool-1 - Starting...   account_app_1  | 2019-09-23 09:51:15.222
>   ERROR [account-service,,,] 286 --- [           main]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception
>   during pool initialization.   account_app_1  |  account_app_1  |
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
>   link failure account_app_1  |  account_app_1  | The last packet sent
>   successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not
>   received any packets from the server. account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]  The last packet sent
>   successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not
>   received any packets from the server. account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na] account_app_1  |        ... 206 common
>   frames omitted account_app_1  | Caused by:
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link
>   failure account_app_1  |  account_app_1  | The last packet sent
>   successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not
>   received any packets from the server. account_app_1  |        at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
>   ~[na:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |
>   ... 214 common frames omitted account_app_1  | Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>   account_app_1  |        at
>   java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>   ~[na:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
>   ~[na:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
>   ~[na:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
>   ~[na:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
>   ~[na:na] account_app_1  |        at
>   java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
>   account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |        at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15] account_app_1  |
>   ... 217 common frames omitted account_app_1  |

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you configure the database's host name and other connection settings?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze. Hostname and database I store in AWS secret manager. Then I start only database through docker-compose and run the application through Intelijii Idea it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running a compose "stack", docker uses its own DNS mechanism.

This means that if you perform a DNS query inside of the `account_app` container for the hostname `mysql`, the query would return the IP address of the container named `mysql` (possibly prefixed with the stack name)

**In short**: Configure your Spring application to connect to a mysql db not on localhost but on `mysql` and you are good to go.

There probably are some environmental variables which you could set to configure this.

Comment: Everyone, thanks for the help. I fixed the issue. As I can see, all the answers are in the correct way and helped me to resolve the issue. From my point of view, the most accurate answer was from @FabianTe. I just did as you advised and everything's working. So I'll mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think you use "localhost" as mysql server hostname,

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
```

try changing it to

```
jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306
```

You cannot localhost inside a docker container.
Best way to do this is by passing jdbc url as a environment variable.

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/code_master
```

Please check the last 5 lines of this sh file, https://github.com/keaz/code_master/blob/develop/build_docker.sh

Answer (score 0):

There is a misconception on port mapping: you're passing all your traffic from host port 3306 to container port 3306, but that's not bidirectional.

To manage your situation, if you're on Linux (it does not works in Windows and Mac) you can add in your docker-compose.yml this configuration, allowing the container to use host services.

> ```
> network_mode: "host"
> ```

Otherwise you could setup your local MySql to accept connection from external IPs and point container database to your IP address.

Please note that this solution would work fine only in local development machine, I strongly suggest to avoid this in any production environment.

Comment: just a question, I'm not familiar with Docker. does this issue occurs if I use mysql image from docker hub ?

Comment: With docker you're running a "light" virtual machine, meaning that each container has it's own network. If you use mysql from docker hub you'd have to "link" the 2 containers in order to manage the connection, you will fail using "localhost" as database connection parameter in your application container

Comment: Hi, @Andrea. I do not fully understand that is wrong with my DB settings. I tried to comment service section and run only mysql through my docker-compose. I started application through Intelijii Idea and it worked fine. I use Mac to run app locally. Can I just add some configurations in docker-compose to fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DenB in Mac "host" network mode does not works. You should setup database to get connection from external and then setup container environment to connect to database using your computer lan IP. 
It's not a docker-compose configuration, it's about networking logic. You should assume your container is a seprarate network computer.